# Why I can't test app by actions on google?

Tags: actions-on-google

I can' test my app(Trivia game show) by actions on google. It just worked for a few days.
But now it says:

> Sorry, this action is not available for your app.
>   In the simulator, you are only able to invoke actions that you have added to your app. For more information on how to invoke your app, click here https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit

Does anyone know the problem?

Thanks KampfTomate :)

Comment: An action that is setup for testing may expire after a few days. You may just need to go to the console and re-enable testing.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solutions**

1. Check the explicit invocations in the **Integrations** of Google Assistant from the **Integrations** tab of Dialogflow. If no invocations are present, add the "**Default Welcome Intent**".
2. Go to the Actions tab in Actions on Google console and then click on **Test** button. This will enable testing in the simulator.
3. If the above methods don't work, try to reopen or refresh the **Actions on Google console** page.